# What impedances do graphics cards expect on H-Sync and V-Sync for VGA monitors?

Tags: connector, resistance, vga

I have a graphics card for a laptop whose driver kills itself if it runs for longer than two minutes with no external monitor attached. To solve that, I decided to make a sort of dummy plug that would be detected as a monitor by PC.

I have managed to find out what impedances video card  expects for most of the pins, but for H-Sync and V-Sync, Google brought up numerous conflicting answers, mostly from people who are guessing.

Comment: Are you sure that it is the lack of a load on the signals, and not a lack of response on the serial monitor ID line, which causes the shutdown?

Comment: @Chris Stratton I'm not. I know that some cards do detect monitors by loading of the signals and monitor ID bits. Anyway, resistors are cheap and if they don't work, I'll probably just add a small microcontroller to provide the EDID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [VESA Plug and Display standard](http://web.archive.org/web/20030704041337/www.vesa.org/public/PnD/pnd.pdf), which uses compatible electrical signaling for analog video, the host is supposed to detect a minimally-capable monitor by looking for 75 Ohm termination on the video lines. Anything beyond basic functionality is determined by reading [EDID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_display_identification_data) information over the I2C lines.

Because EDID is so old, the video card may not even bother checking for a monitor without it. You could probably fool the video card into believing a monitor with any desired capability is present with an appropriately programmed I2C EEPROM or microcontroller.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because of link to VESA standard. The standard says that the Synchronization Signal lines should have 2 kΩ to +5 V DC.

Answer (score 0):

Why isn't more likely to be something like bad capacitors on the inverter for the LCD display? For external monitors this is a very common symptom - I have a monitor on the bench that pretty much runs for a minute or two then the backlight goes black (but you can still the LCD pixels being driven if you look hard)

Comment: According to the question, it is not the monitor, but the graphics source that fails.  And does so in a controlled way.

Comment: It is indeed the graphics card that is problematic. As far as I can see, it tries to enter some sort of power saving mode which results in BSOD.